# Loading mask not appaear for full screen

Tags: extjs

How to load loading screen mask to entire window instead of perticular object in extjs?

Comment: I am using 
ext.getbody(),{msg:'Loading...'});

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Ext.getBody().mask('this is a full body mask');
```

[Doc](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.Element-method-mask)